# POSIX raw read/write

Tags: posix, bsd

Can anyone explain how the read/write operations performed on /dev node using BSD read() write() operation reaches the HDD.

Does it go thru File System or It directly interacts thru the device drivers....

Answer (score 1):

It directly interacts with the device driver.  Some operating systems (not certain about OS X), will put use the buffer cache, but some will bypass it.  In some cases, it even depends on the device node.  For example, OS X has /dev/disk* as well as /dev/rdisk*, where the rdisk* device nodes are raw access.

Answer (score 1):

For example, take the following case. You open the fictional /dev/bd device, which is a HDD. The kernel, in order to serve the system call request, first take an attempt to find the inode associated with the /dev/bd path. After it succeeded, it's being determined, what is the type of the inode, has been read just now. In our case, the type of the inode will be BLOCK-SPECIFIC. At this point, the kernel knows that this inode represents a driver(a block-specific device's driver). Every device has a (major_id,minor_id) pair associated, they identify the different devices. In the inode, it can be found, and the kernel knows exactly, which driver can serve the request. And depends on the request, the appropriate function of the driver will be invoked(for example read).